# Is there any way to determine if the router is forwarding WoL packet to the NIC card while the computer is turned off?

Tags: router, network-adapter, wireshark, wake-on-lan, arp

I am having hard time figuring out whether the problem is with the router not forwarding the packets to the NIC OR the problem is the NIC not waking the PC or other hidden settings that are preventing wake up.

In either case, I want to know if there is any way to check whether the Wake On LAN (WOL) packet is actually received by the NIC or not. Because that's the first step in troubleshooting my system.

I used Wireshark but, this is first time ever I used this program, and I was able to see the packet is received by the router, then, the router sends an ARP request -- on the note it says "Tell me who has  IP".

So, When the PC is sleeping or shutdown and listening for WoL packet, how do I determine if the packet is actually received by the NIC or not? Does NIC have any record keeping of packets/events it receives?

Answer (score 1):

That the router is making an ARP who-has request suggests that the magic packet has been sent via the IP layer:  this is beyond the scope of the WoL protocol, which specifies a layer 2 (ethernet) broadcast frame with a payload of `FF:FF:FF` immediately followed by the NIC's MAC address repeated sixteen times.

So, if the router is trying to send such a packet to a specific IP address, it will fail to wake a sleeping system, as the ARP negotiation will not complete, so the packet will not be put onto the wire.

The router would have to send a packet to the broadcast address instead, which requires no ARP resolution:  such a packet is sent to all stations, on all ports.   An ethernet broadcast packet can usually be sent by using 255.255.255.255 as a destination, or by the 1s-compliment of the `netmask` parameter logically ANDed to the `network` parameter.

For example:

> A network of 192.168.2.0 with a netmask of 255.255.254.0, has a
>   broadcast address of (192.168.2.0 AND 0.0.1.255), which is
>   192.168.3.255.

Unfortunately, due to Denial-of-Service attacks based on packet multiplication exploiting broadcast addresses, such `subnet directed broadcast` packets are not usually forwarded across the public Internet, so it's not generally possible to use WoL from non-local networks that are outside local configuration management.